# Linq ToList() fails to trigger Immediate Execution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having a very peculiar problem: the `ToList()` extension method is failing to convert results to a list. here is my code, standard boilerplate linq query, I converted `ToList()` twice for good measure

```
var assets = new List<Asset>();

using (var ctx = new LeaseContext())
{
    assets = ctx.Assets.OrderBy(o => o.Reference).Where(w => w.Status == AssetStatus.Active).ToList();

    assets.ToList();
}

return assets;
```

yet the assets are still a list of `System.Data.Entities.DynamicProxies`....

I've never had this problem before.

Comment: Why  do you use ToList() for the same variable ?

Comment: The second `ToList()` doesn't do anything since you're not using the result of the `ToList()`.

Comment: I know the second ToList() is redundant, I just wanted to test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is lazy loading. When lazy loading is enabled in EF (by default), then (again, by default) EF creates dynamic proxies for each entity. It's required for loading related entities. Dynamic proxy will be inherited from entity class. So in your case it will be inherited from `Asset`. But dynamic proxy will have reference to the context which created its instance. And it will override navigation properties (which are virtual) to query entities via context which is stored in dynamic proxy.

And it's completely legal to add instances of derived types to list of base type.

If you don't want dynamic proxies, then just disable lazy loading and proxy creation:

```
ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; // turn-off loading on-demand
ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; // turn-off wrapper class generation
```

Technically you can just turn-off proxy generation and lazy loading will not work. But I prefer to turn-off both settings explicitly.

Comment: I've added the statement, but still doesn't work.

using (var ctx = new LeaseContext())
   {
    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    assets = ctx.Assets.OrderBy(o => o.Reference).Where(w => w.Status == AssetStatus.Active).Select(x => x).ToList();
   }

   
   return assets;

Comment: @franklores you should add this statement before you use `cxt` to query assets

Comment: @franklores sorry, I forgot about second configuration setting - there is separate one for disabling proxies creation

Comment: This works! Thanks. Is there a way to set this globally?

Comment: @franklores yes, you can use `Configuration` in constructor of context